# Getting undefined error on callback argument in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I have written the viewCart function in the base controller and invoking it from the home controller, but I'm getting `undefined` error on callback argument in home.js

> home.js

```
sync.parallel([
        base.categoryMenu,
        base.viewCart(req,res,callback)
    ],
    function(err, results){

    });
```

> base.js

```
 exports.viewCart = function(req,res,callback) {
         request({
            uri:webServiceURL.viewCart,
            method: "GET",
            }, function(error, response, body) {

                if(response["headers"]["set-cookie"]){
                    res.set("set-cookie",response["headers"]["set-cookie"]);    
                }   

              callback(null,body);

            });


};
```

Comment: Why would it be defined? You don't appear to have set a value for it in home.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to wrap your functions with a function receiving a callback argument, [like the documentation explains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#parallel-tasks-callback):

```
sync.parallel([
    function (callback) {
        base.categoryMenu();
        callback();
    },
    function (callback) {
        base.viewCart(req,res,callback);
    }
],
function(err, results){
    if (!err) console.log(results);
});
```

I'm assuming that `base.categoryMenu` is a function, and if so, you have to call it with the `()`.